# How to deploy wildfly 15 with java 11?

Tags: wildfly, java-11

I have some problem to deploy my application with Wildfly 15. I recently upgrade to Java 11, so, wildfly 15 only deploys with java 11. I have some problem when I starts, log:

How I fix it?

```
    org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: java.se
at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1266)
at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1622)
at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1650)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:296)
at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:437)
```

Comment: I don't know why Wildfly is looking for the "java.se" aggregator but I assume you can workaround this by running with `--add-modules java.se`.

Comment: Yeah! It's Working, thank you, but only works when I run "standalone.bat" in wildfly/bin, when I run on eclipse , the same problem has been come, you know why ?

Comment: Alan, Im already finish! In the vm Arguments on Wildfly configurations in eclipse, I added "-add-modules java.se" and worked. Thanks for the help !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Wildfly 14 with java 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52852192/how-to-run-wildfly-14-with-java-11)