# Deployment is failing with org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException error for wildfly-15.0.1.Final with OpenJdk-11

Tags: wildfly, openjdk-11

I am upgrading my application from JDK 7 to OpenJDk-11 and Application server from JBoss-AS-7.1 to wildfly-15.0.1.Final. But deployment is failing for below error:

```
org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: java.se
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1266)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1622)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1650)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:296)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:437)
```

Tried with wildfly-16.0.0.Final also but got the same error.

Comment: I would recommend doing the upgrade in steps. Upgrading application server and java version simultaneously is impossible to work at once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Wildfly 14 with java 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52852192/how-to-run-wildfly-14-with-java-11)

Comment: How are you starting WildFly?

Comment: It was the same issue as with WildFly 14.