# Eclipse 4.14.0 cannot set correct execution environment for the Server Runtime Environment for Wildfly 14

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly-14

I'm trying to move my projects from eclipse 4.9.0 to 4.14.0 and I am experiencing problems when creating the Server Runtime Environment for Wildfly 14.0.1. When I try to create the runtime environment, I cannot set the correct Execution environment because only JavaSE-1.8 is offered in the drop down menu. It should be possible to select JavaSE-1.11

[eclipse 4.14.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDmij.png)

In eclipse 4.9.0 I can choose among all the java environments I have installed

[eclipse 4.9.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMbxH.png)

I cannot see what is the problem. I'm running eclipse on Win 10 64-bit and I have jdk1.8.0_92, jdk-11.0.1 and jre1.8.0_231 installed.
I have also tried to install it on an fresh win 10 computer with only jdk-11.0.1 installed, but the problem remained.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JVM 9 there ware essential changes like module system. One of consequences is for instance this bug in [WildFly 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52852192/how-to-run-wildfly-14-with-java-11). I suppose RedHat wanted to help developers and displays in the newer Eclipse plugin only Java versions under witch WildFly 14 runs flawless.

The first version of WildFly that officially works well with new module system is [WildFly 15](https://wildfly.org/news/2018/12/13/WildFly15-Final-Released/). That's why when you configure WildFly 15, also Eclipse 4.14 will show you not only Java 8, but also higher JREs if you have configured them in Eclipse, e.g. JavaSE-11 or JavaSE-13.

If you want to force WildFly 14 to run under Java 11, you can configure Java 11 to pretend to be Java 8: Windows --> Preferences --> Installed JREs --> Execution Environments --> select JavaSE-8 in the left pane and select JRE 11 in right pane.

Comment: Thank you mentallurg, however I am bit mad on RedHat because when they launched Wildfly 14 it was said that it is compatible to JavaSE-11 and yes I'm aware of that modules system problem, but this what they did, did not help me, instead it burned some of my precious time.